# Can You Save Data To A Dictionary From A Text Document?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.3

I can't find any way to add data to dictionaries from text documents. Wait, is it even possible?

e.g.

```
with open("D:\Programming - Python\S.A.M.I\Words/Pos.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
posread=f.read()
```

(and then have this split each word using .split(,) to a dictionary)

Comment: What's the problem with any existing code? What's the input - what's the expected output... etc...

Comment: I needed to compare to lots of data to output the similar words in both. I tried using lists and tuples with no result and now I'm trying dictionaries. I have a file of words which I wish to split into a dictionary and then split the words of the users input into a dictionary. Then I will be able to run and see which (if any) words feature in both the text document and the users input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input `in.txt` is in the following format:

```
val1 val2
val3 val4
```

you can read it in the following way:

```
f = file("in.txt")
d = {}
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    c0,c1 = line.split()
    d[c0] = c1
```

...and now you have the dictionary `d`.